# Removing duplicate from TStringList

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I am parsing a dataset and assigning values to `TStringList` i want to avoid the duplicates. I use the following code but still duplicates are inserted.

```
  channelList := TStringList.Create;
  channelList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
  try
    dataset.First;
    while not dataset.EOF do
    begin
        channelList.Add(dataset.FieldByName('CHANNEL_INT').AsString)  ;
        dataset.Next;
    end;
```

why does the duplicates added?

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStringList.Duplicates

Comment: BTW `dataset.FieldByName('CHANNEL_INT')` is slow unsorted operation. Cache it into the `var F: TField` before the loop start

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You did read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStringList.Duplicates , didn't you ?

Then you missed the most repeated word there - "sorted"

```
channelList.Sorted := true
```

---

```
var F: TField;

channelList := TStringList.Create;
channelList.Sorted := True;
channelList.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

try
   dataset.First;
   F := dataset.FieldByName('CHANNEL_INT');
   while not dataset.EOF do
   begin
      channelList.Add(F.AsString);
      dataset.Next;
   end;
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, even the user is not aware/care about the scalability :)

Comment: @RBA well, i think the user with 2K+ karma should at least *know*, if not *care*. What about `.Sorted` miss... well... we all keep makinf the most stupid mistakes once and again despite any experience gained before  Perhaps it was just his bad day. :-)

Comment: Probably that kind of day :)

Comment: @RBA OTOH that makes me wonder what is the datasat ? kind of ISAM ? JSON/XML ? cause the 1st instinct to me would be adding one SQL term to the query so that the dataset just could not contain those duplicates in the 1st

Comment: @Arioch'The: oh i am sorry, i am new to Delphi my 2k+ is on c++

Answer (score 9):

Think out of the box and avoid the duplicates up front?

I don't know what DB you are using but for example on SQL server it is just a matter of querying:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT CHANNEL_INT FROM MYTABLE';
```

and then you can add the results to your `TStringList` without being worried about duplicates.

Comment: Why would one fetch many results and filter them out on the client side. If those filtered records are ignored anywhere else in the application, there's no need to fetch them and this is the most correct answer. [+1]

Comment: @TLama if that is the query to fill the list, yes. But  it might be the query with a different goal and getting list of different values is just - for example - for grid auto-filter.

Comment: @Arioch, that's what I meant - *If those filtered records are ignored anywhere else in the application, there's no need to fetch them*...

Comment: @TLama well, in my book this can go as a second step in the answer, showing how to refactor and optimize the code *after* the question at it given would be answered by face value, "in the box". IMHO.

Comment: @Arioch, well, I said it wrong. It's not the most correct answer, it's (probably) the best suggestion.

Comment: @TLama but it can be remade into the best answer. *whosrdaddy* ?

Comment: I agree this is not an answer to his question, so Arioch deserves the accept here...